# Passing lists into a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am a newbie to C# and Threading and this is a very simple question, but has me really stuck. I did search on this site but could not find an answer similar to my scenario:

I have a method say Parent() and in that I create a typed list, every nth time I pass it off to a Task. I have the problem of when to clear the list and release the memory since it keeps growing. I tried clearing list at the end of the task, if I clear list with the Parent method, the list is empty in the thread.

Could someone help me? I know this is a very simple problem, but would appreciate the help.

```
    public void Parent()
    {
     List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
     for (int i = 0; i< N; i++)
     {
        list.Add(new MyType {Var = "blah"});

      if ( i% 10 == 0) //every tentth time we send a task out tou a thread
      {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteToDB(new List<MyType>(list))); 
       //here I am              sending a new instance of the list

        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteToDB((list))); 
        //here I am sending same instance

        list.Clear();

         //if I clear here the list sent to the WriteToDB is empty
        //if I do not, the memory keeps growing up and crashes the app 
      }

      private void WriteToDB(List<MyType> list)
      {
       //do some calculations with the list 
       //insert into db 
       list.Clear(); 
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Can you please show the full Class Definition, also it appears that you are nesting a method inside of another method I Parent the Class..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a closure bug.

The lambda `() => WriteToDB(new List<MyType>(list))` isn't executed until the new `Task` starts.
This will sometimes be after your call to `list.Clear()`.

The fix is to capture the copy of the list outside the lambda:

```
var chunk = new List<MyType>(list);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteToDB(chunk));

list.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create the new list before starting the thread:

```
var newList = new List<MyType>(list);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteToDB(newList)); 
list.Clear();
```

This way, the new list is ready before the new thread starts, so it's safe to immediately clear the original one.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a error. This means the parent method is modifying the collection as the task operation is still r unning. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()

Comment: @Santino hm, there must be more code you're not showing.  Are you using a `Where` clause somewhere?

Comment: no, it is very simple code that I am writing. IDNK what the "where clause" is. In the Lambda?

Comment: @Santino I really don't know. Maybe somewhere in the "Do some calculations" section.  The only other thing I can suggest is to try removing `list.Clear()` inside the `WriteToDB` method -- you don't need that, it's a local object that will be garbage disposed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( i% 10 == 0) //every tentth time we send a task out tou a thread
{
   // clone your list before starting the task
   var listToProcess = new List<MyType>(list);
   list.Clear();

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteToDB(listToProcess)); 
}
```